# R function parameters in quotes / not in quotes

Tags: r

In R, some functions expect the function parameters to be in quotes, like this:

```
summarySE(xx, measurevar= "X1F1", groupvars="genotype",na.rm=TRUE)
```

others seem happy with the same parameter without ", like this:

```
aov(data=xx,X1F1~genotype)
```

How can I convert from a string like "X1F1" to the X1F1 required by the formula
Here's my data

```
    genotype      X1F1       X2F1
 1         R  43.33877   7.881666
 2         R 130.34433  65.056984
 3         R  53.39783  11.985018
 4         R  23.45456   5.683387
 5         R 138.50044  61.194956
 6         R 108.63964  39.581222
 7         R 153.60738  55.854238
 8         T 264.96127 108.751380
 9         T 222.94124 119.695112
10         T 119.55373  36.793537
11         T  34.97877  12.285921
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: look under _Arguments_ section in documentation of functions by `?aov` or `?summarySE`, then try understanding the difference

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.frame` column names in formula. Two `lm` below will give the same result:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))
# Option 1. As formula
lm(y ~ x, df)

# Option 2. As data.frame index
lm(df[, "y"] ~ df[, "x"])
```